# PyQt5 are taking the screenshot without waiting the api response

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, python-3.6, webpage-screenshot

I using pyqt5 for taking the screenshot to the URL. it's the react component. it takes the screenshot only component. don't wait till the API response. wanna take a screenshot after get the API response.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings


class Screenshot(QWebEngineView):

    def capture(self, url, output_file):
        self.output_file = output_file
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loaded)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontShowOnScreen)
        self.show()

    def on_loaded(self):
        size = self.page().contentsSize().toSize()
        self.resize(size)
        qt = QTimer()
        qt.setInterval(8000)
        qt.setSingleShot(True)
        qt.singleShot(8000, self.take_screenshot)

    def take_screenshot(self):
        self.grab().save(self.output_file, b'PNG')
        self.app.quit()



app = QApplication([])
s = Screenshot()
s.app = app
s.capture('https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html', 'webpage20.png')
app.exec_()
```

Note: Under `s.capture` param URL is just for the example purpose.

Comment: The `loadFinished` signal only notifies that the *loading* of the page has been completed, not that it has been rendered. Also, since you're not showing the widget by using the `WA_DontShowOnScreen` attribute, it cannot be rendered, and you wouldn't grab the page anyway, since `grab()` only grabs the *window* (which is not rendered, by the way, due to the attribute above). Finally, `QTimer.singleShot` is a static, you don't need to create a new instance to do that, it should just be `QTimer.singleShot(8000, self.take_screenshot)`.

Comment: I don't understand your question, I have the following with your code: https://i.imgur.com/dcmbt85.png

Comment: My question is when I take the screenshot from the URL, it takes the screenshot without waiting for the load content from the API response. @eyllanesc